# jQuery DataTable plugin says "row" isn't a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Before I get into it, I **have** checked out the posts on here that ask this same question, however none of those answers have worked in my situation.

I am trying to delete a row from the DataTable plugin. The table initializes without issue, however when I try to delete a row using the `.row().remove()` functions, I get the following error:

> Error: TypeError: pagesTable.row is not a function

This jsFiddle shows this working perfectly:
[Removing row from DataTable](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd6UQ/)

Here is my header:

```
<!-- DATA TABES SCRIPT -->
<script src="js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedRow = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        pagesTable = $('#pages-table').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

And here is my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn', function(){
        selectedRow = $(this).data('id');
        pagesTable.row('#row_22').remove().draw(false);
        /*
        $('#row_'+selectedRow).fadeOut(function(){

        });
        */
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. It appears that the version of DataTables that I was using (v.1.09) doesn't support the `row()` function. After upgrading to v1.10, the script is working perfectly.